# I'd like to bring your attention to a bug on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed

Good day, users of Islam.SE! I've recently stumbled across a bug that negatively impacts the ability of SE users to input Arabic text, for which I have filed a bug report on Meta Stack Exchange: [I can't post a certain string of Arabic text here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233476/224428).

This bug doesn't affect me directly (since I neither know nor type in Arabic), but I know that a number of you do use Arabic in your posts on this website, so I thought it might be helpful to bring your attention to this issue, in case some of you might have also experienced the same issue or know why it's happening or whatnot.